# Python ctypes passing pointer to mutable pointer

Tags: ctypes

I have following C library

```c
struct algo_hdl_str_t {
  size_t size;
  void* data;
};

typedef algo_hdl_str_t* algo_hdl_t;

/**
 * @brief Encode data
 *
 * @param type[in] type of data
 * @param data[in] pointer to data
 * @param size[in] size of data
 * @param hdl[out] handler to allocated encoded data
 *
 * @return status
 */
algo_status_t algo_encode(algo_type_t const type, void const* const data, size_t const size, algo_hdl_t* const hdl);

/**
 * @brief Free message memory
 *
 * @param hdl[in] handler to message
 */
void algo_free(algo_hdl_t const hdl);
```

For more understanding what this library do here is unit test:

```cpp
algo_hdl_t hdl_enc;
char *in_str = (char *)"some_weird_string";
CHECK(ALGO_SUCCESS == algo_encode(ALGO_GENERAL, in_str, strlen(in_str), &hdl_enc));
CHECK(0U == memcmp(algo_data(&hdl_enc), expected_data, algo_data_size(&hdl_enc)));
algo_free(hdl_enc)
```

I want to make python bind of this memory, but I am failing to pass pointer to handler in Python bind code

```py
import ctypes, os
from enum import Enum

class MessType(Enum):
    UNKNOWN = 0
    EXAMPLE = 1

def encode(message_type, data):
    path = os.path.abspath('../../../build/libalgo.dylib')
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(path)

    lib.algo_encode.argtypes = ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_void_p
    lib.algo_encode.restype = ctypes.c_int

    handler_mem = ctypes.create_string_buffer(8)
    handler = ctypes.cast(handler_mem, ctypes.c_void_p)
  
    data_ptr = (ctypes.c_void_p).from_buffer_copy(data)

    result = lib.algo_encode(message_type.value, data_ptr, len(data), handler)

    print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = b'some_weird_string' + b'\x00'
    encode(MessType.EXAMPLE, data)
```

How to pass last argument of algo_encode to make it work? Currently I have 'segmentation fault` error since - I guess - I am passing pointer to immutable data... I did tried more ways "to pass this handler", but every one failed.

```py
handler = ctypes.c_void_p() # fails with C library assertion telling we are passing nullptr
handler = ctypes.c_void_p(1) # failes with segmentation fault
```

Please give me a little guidence since I am new in python :) Thank you

Comment: I found the problem: this does not work ```data_ptr = (ctypes.c_void_p).from_buffer_copy(data)``` thread can be marked as solved :)

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as the answer, or just delete it.

Comment: @MarkTolonen When I end working on this I will surely post solution to make it a worth stack overflow post

Answer (score 2):

For an issue like this, making a simple working example of the C code helps clarify how it works.  Here's my best guess.  It allocates the return structure and fills it out with the provided data and length:

test.c

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define API __declspec(dllexport)

struct algo_hdl_str_t {
  size_t size;
  void* data;
};

typedef struct algo_hdl_str_t* algo_hdl_t;
typedef int algo_status_t;
typedef int algo_type_t;

API algo_status_t algo_encode(algo_type_t const type, void const* const data, size_t const size, algo_hdl_t* const hdl) {
    *hdl = malloc(sizeof(struct algo_hdl_str_t));
    (*hdl)->data = malloc(size);
    memcpy((*hdl)->data, data, size);
    (*hdl)->size = size;
    return 0;
}

API void algo_free(algo_hdl_t const hdl) {
    free(hdl->data);
    free(hdl);
}
```

Here is the `ctypes` Python code to read it:

```py
import ctypes as ct

# Matching structure definition
class algo_hdl_str_t(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('size',ct.c_size_t),
                ('data',ct.c_void_p))

# Equivalent typedef
algo_hdl_t = ct.POINTER(algo_hdl_str_t)

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.algo_encode.argtypes = ct.c_int,ct.c_void_p,ct.c_size_t,ct.POINTER(algo_hdl_t)
dll.algo_encode.restype = ct.c_int
dll.algo_free.argtypes = algo_hdl_t,
dll.algo_free.restype = None

hdl = algo_hdl_t()
data = b'some byte data\0nulls ok'
dll.algo_encode(1,data,len(data),ct.byref(hdl))
print(hdl.contents.size)
# hdl.contents obtains the structure.
# Cast hdl.contents.data from void* to char* and slice the pointer to the
# desired length to view the raw data.
print(ct.cast(hdl.contents.data,ct.POINTER(ct.c_char))[:hdl.contents.size])
dll.algo_free(hdl)
```

Output:

```
23
b'some byte data\x00nulls ok'
```